# How to change text form fields by selecting radio button options

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have two option 1- Vacational 2- Longterm Now what I want here is when I select these option from radio buttons form is populated and form has following fields:

1- Season
2- Dates
3- Daily
4- Weekly
5- Monthly

Now what I want here when I select value longterm I want to display only Monthly field from popup form and if I select vacational all the fields should be displayed.

My html where these options are:

```
     <div class="m-b-10 m-t-10">

            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="is_vacation" name="property_type" checked> Vacation
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="is_long_term" name="property_type"> Long Term
            </label>

        </div>
```

and my controller

```
      if ($search == "vacationRental") {

            // $properties = Property::where('is_vacation', '=', 1)->get();
            $properties = Property::where('status', '=', 1)->where('is_vacation', '=', 1)->get();
            return view('admin.property.index')
                        ->with('properties', $properties)
                        ->with('seasons', $seasons);

        } elseif ($search == "longTerm") {

            // $properties = Property::where('is_long_term', '=', 1)->get();
            $properties = Property::where('status', '=', 1)->where('is_long_term', '=', 1)->get();
            return view('admin.property.index')
                        ->with('properties', $properties)
                        ->with('seasons', $seasons);

        }
```

do I need to create a new view for this or it can be done with JS I think it can be done with JS but I don't have an idea how to do this. need your help

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: are you looking forward to use Js for implementing this functionality?

Comment: yeah if it can be done with JS then my work will be solved

Comment: onchange function will solved this functionality but i dont know much about js

Comment: so what you can do is create two div one for vacation and another for longterm and add corresponding controls to them. Then using Js on select of particular radio btn hide and show these divs using css property display :none and display:block

Comment: can we have chat?

Comment: or can you show me with code ?

Comment: below i added a code snippet. Have a look and revert me back if i could help you in anyway else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174883/discussion-between-deepak-verma-and-shahzad1122).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Radio Buttons</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
    label{ margin-right: 15px; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a Sample Example you can refer

Comment: Thanks for sharing but its i think different scenario can we have chat please so i can explain you clearly about my problem

Comment: I will love to rate your answer

Comment: new in here could you guide me how to chat?